# What is the difference between pidof and pgrep?

Tags: process

When I use either of these commands with an argument as the name of a process, both of them return the exact same number. Are they the same commands? Are they two different commands that do the same thing? Is one of them an alias to the other?

```
pidof firefox
pgrep firefox
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The programs `pgrep` and `pidof` are not quite the same thing, but they are very similar.  For example:

```
$ pidof 'firefox'
5696
$ pgrep '[i]ref'
5696
$ pidof '[i]ref'
$ printf '%s\n' "$?"
1
```

As you can see, `pidof` failed to find a match for `[i]ref`.  This is because `pidof program` returns a list of all process IDs associated with a program called `program`.  On the other hand, `pgrep re` returns a list of all process IDs associated with a program whose name matches the regular expression `re`.

In their most basic forms, the equivalence is actually:

```
$ pidof 'program'
$ pgrep '^program$'
```

As yet another concrete example, consider:

```
$ ps ax | grep '[w]atch'
   12 ?        S      0:04 [watchdog/0]
   15 ?        S      0:04 [watchdog/1]
   33 ?        S<     0:00 [watchdogd]
18451 pts/5    S+     0:02 watch -n600 tail log-file
$ pgrep watch
12
15
33
18451
$ pidof watch
18451
```

Answer (score 8):

Fox has mentioned that `pgrep` searches using regular expressions, while `pidof` does not.

But `pgrep` also has a lot more options available:

- With `-u "$UID"` you can match only processes belonging to the current user.
- With `--parent` you can find the child processes of a given process.
- You can select the `--oldest` or `--newest` of the matching processes.
- ...and various others listed on the man page...

Let's find out which package each process belongs to (on apt systems):

```
$ dpkg -S "$(which pidof)"
sysvinit-utils: /bin/pidof

$ dpkg -S "$(which pgrep)"
procps: /usr/bin/pgrep
```

On pacman systems:

```
$ pacman -Qo "$(which pidof)"
/usr/bin/pidof is owned by procps-ng 3.3.17-1

$ pacman -Qo "$(which pgrep)"
/usr/bin/pgrep is owned by procps-ng 3.3.17-1
```

On RPM systems:

```
$ rpm -qf "$(which pidof)"
... ?
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a note: `pidof` MAY treat everything after the last slash as the `program name`:

```
fang@debian:~$ ps -ax | grep k3s | head -n1
    528 ?        Ssl  634:37 /usr/local/bin/k3s server
fang@debian:~$ pgrep k3s
528
fang@debian:~$ pidof k3s
fang@debian:~$ pidof /usr/local/bin/k3s
fang@debian:~$ pidof '/usr/local/bin/k3s server'
528
fang@debian:~$ pidof 'k3s server'
528
```

---

Update: As Stéphane Chazelas said, `pidof` actually **match** any of:

- `Name:` field in `/proc/pid/status`
- the first argument in `/proc/pid/cmdline`
- the base name of the first argument in `/proc/pid/cmdline`

In most cases, there should be a `NUL` after each arg. eg. sleep:

```
fang@debian:~$ sleep infinity &
[1] 2076966
fang@debian:~$ pidof sleep
2076966
fang@debian:~$ xxd /proc/2076966/cmdline
00000000: 736c 6565 7000 696e 6669 6e69 7479 00    sleep.infinity.
fang@debian:~$ head -n1 /proc/2076966/status
Name:   sleep
```

It is a bit special because the `argv[0]` contains a whitespace:

```
fang@debian:~$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/k3s
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 54001664  7月  3 20:16 /usr/local/bin/k3s
fang@debian:~$ head -n1 /proc/528/status
Name:   k3s-server
fang@debian:~$ head -n1 /proc/528/cmdline && echo
/usr/local/bin/k3s server
fang@debian:~$ xxd /proc/528/cmdline 
00000000: 2f75 7372 2f6c 6f63 616c 2f62 696e 2f6b  /usr/local/bin/k
00000010: 3373 2073 6572 7665 7200 0000 0000 0000  3s server.......
```

In conclusion, to get its pid, you can:

```
fang@debian:~$ pgrep k3s-server
528
fang@debian:~$ pidof k3s-server
528
fang@debian:~$ pidof 'k3s server'
528
```

You cannot:

```
fang@debian:~$ pgrep 'k3s server'
```

Because it only match

- `Name:` field in `/proc/pid/status`
- (Seems it is the same to the part inside `(...)` in `/proc/pid/stat`, right?)

Comment: Note that `pgrep` matches on the process name (the `Name:` field in `/proc/pid/status` or the part inside `(...)` in `/proc/pid/stat` as show with `ps -o comm`) by default while `pidof` matches on the `argv[0]` (or its basename  as you rightly point out) of  the last execve() the process or its ancestor made (`/proc/pid/cmdline`, `ps -o args`), falling back to the process name only if argv[0] is empty or there's no args (execve() called with an empty arg list, or kernel tasks that have never run a execve()). `pgrep -f` matches on the arg list (joined with spaces)

Comment: On my system (Debian testing where `pidof` is from `sysvinit-utils` version 3.07), `pidof` only matches on the process name if `argv[0]` is empty  or unset. After `exec -a foo sleep 20 &`, `pidof foo` matches but not `pidof sleep`. While with `exec -a '' sleep 20`, `pidof sleep` matches but `pidof ''` doesn't.

Comment: `Name:` in `/proc/pid/status` is the same as part inside `(...)` in /proc/pid/stat which is the process name (note: it's limited to 15 bytes on Linux), except that  in `/proc/pid/status` some characters are encoded using backslash escape sequences. For instance newline is represented as `\n`. For the text that `pgrep` regexps match against, it seems those characters are replaced with `?`. For `pidof` I don't know.